# Colorized REPL for Common Lisp

Tags: vim, common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop, colorize

I was wondering if there is a way to colorize a Common Lisp REPL. Although terminfo seems to lay some groundwork for that, I've yet to find a library that actually uses it for coloring. Has someone done it already? Vim plugins and implementation-specific libraries (such as linedit for SBCL) are welcome.

PS: I am aware of Emacs, and would prefer a Vim alternative if the solution has to be wrapped inside an editor. My preference of SBCL against CLISP, on the other hand, isn't as critical.

Comment: I am aware of slimv too and find it pretty awesome, specially the parenthesis and code autocompletion. Although it seems to have some "features", like accidental removal of REPL-generated text resulting in a hung REPL until it's cleared. The "optimal" solution I'm looking for would be for a pure Lisp terminal, for example if I know I'm not going to need to edit files.

Comment: If you find any bugs in slimv, please report them to me (the author). Please tell me how to reproduce the hanging of REPL and I'll try to fix the problem.

Comment: Pleased to meet you :)

On the bug I mentioned, if I accidentally kill lines of the REPL buffer before the prompt, the REPL stops responding to newlines. Undoing gets it responsive if the damage is not extensive, and reloading the connection with `,c` always fixes it.
I'm relatively new to Vim; I've used it for editing but haven't get my hands dirty with its innards yet; is it possible to mark only part of a buffer, like everything behind and above the end of the prompt, read-only?
Congratulations on the work so far :D Apart from that little detail, it's great!

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the problem you mentioned. Now REPL shall not stop responding to newlines after deleting some lines from the buffer. Please fetch it from the [repo](https://bitbucket.org/kovisoft/slimv).

Answer (score 1):

By now, slimv + vim as reminded by wvxvw will do. Finding a standalone CL library is pending.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2531